# SQL View Assign Alternating Data from Another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cannot explain this thoroughly with words as English is not my native language so I will try visual presentation. First, I have a table that looks like this let's call it `tblPerson`:

```
tblPerson
ID   Name
1    John
2    Paul
3    James
```

Then I have another table `tblPhones`:

```
tblPhones
ID   Mobile
1    123456
2    654321
```

Now for my question, is it possible to create a view that will look like this:

```
Person-Phone
Name    Mobile
John    123456
Paul    654321
James   123456
```

What I want to display is a list of person, and use the tblPhones to assign the mobile column but assign it alternately. So if a new person is added lets say `Mark`. The view would look like this:

```
Person-Phone
Name    Mobile
John    123456
Paul    654321
James   123456
Mark    654321
```

How can I query this?

Comment: Whether tblPhones will be having only two rows? what if this table contains more than two rows .. that time you want to use all the values from tblPhones and then start again from row one .. is it?

Comment: @pratikgarg Yes, in case a new phone is added, it will also update the view, that's why I want to use view so the changes will reflect immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Name, Mobile
FROM (
  SELECT Name, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) As rn
  FROM tblPerson) AS t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Mobile, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS rn,
         COUNT(*) OVER () AS cnt
  FROM tblPhones
) AS t2 ON (t1.rn - 1) % cnt + 1 = t2.rn
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d90d4/3)

Comment: You did it! For now this is magic to me I will try to understand how it worked. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

@Giorgos beat me to it, but here's my version. You don't need the `row_number` window function assuming the IDs are contiguous (if they're not, you do :).

```
CREATE TABLE #tblPerson (ID INT,Name VARCHAR(5));
CREATE TABLE #tblPhones (ID INT, Mobile VARCHAR(6));

INSERT INTO #tblPerson(ID, Name) VALUES( 1, 'John'),( 2, 'Paul'),( 3, 'James');
INSERT INTO #tblPhones(ID, Mobile) VALUES( 1,'123456'),( 2,'654321');

SELECT
  Name, Mobile
FROM #tblPerson
JOIN #tblPhones ON #tblPhones.ID = ((#tblPerson.ID-1) % (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tblPhones) +1)
ORDER BY #tblPerson.ID
```

Comment: Thanks! Also works, yes, IDs are auto incremented, will look into this.